# VS 2012 Add New Asset. Custom extension type.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

In VS 2010 in .vsixmanifest editor there was a content section in which you could add new content by such dialog:

[image]
Here you could select type "Custom extension type" and textbox for inputting this custom type will appear.

In VS 2012 editor has been changed and now it is "Add New Asset":
[image]

And there is no such type. How I could add such item in VS 2012? I need this because I need to add custom StartPage.

Answer (score 0):

You can type anything you want in the "Type" dropdown. Typing "StartPage" should still work.

Comment: It doesn't. My "main" extension expects that startpage extension will compile in dll, but it still produce .vsix package. So I am getting `Metadata file '...\StartPageTemplate.dll' could not be found` error.

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Build? Or during VS trying to load it?

Comment: on the build. Project with StartpPage doesnt build .dll, only .vsix

Comment: Did you start with a "VSIX Project" from the templates? That's set up to neither build nor include your empty .dll.

And how does this relate to my answer? Is this an unrelated problem, or one that happened when you tried it?

Comment: Well. I have 2 extension projects. One is extension which adds start page to VS(it is a project upgraded from extension for VS2010, you cannot create new 2012 extension project which will add start page).Another one is main extension project. I want to "integrate" start page extension to my main project, so that user would have 1 .vsix file instead of two. But when I am trying to do so - I got an error, main project expects that startpage project will compile as .dll but it still produces .vsix.